# How do you use 그보다?

Tags: vocabulary

I tried to look for it's meaning but mostly they explain it as a comparative word.

Before that i found this sentence "그보다 오늘 있잖아~."
But it doesn't seems like comparative sentence, then again i don't know the meaning of this sentence..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the given sentence, it is used to change the topic of the conversation. A rough equivalent in English would be "by the way." And yes, it comes from the comparative "-보다". One might also say "그것보다, (오늘 있잖아) ..."

You can understand it like "(What I want to talk about) more than (what we've been talking is), today, you know, ..."

Comment: Ah, so it was like "other than that, today, you know..."?

Comment: Oh, yes. "Other than that" seems to catch the tone quite well.